# Selecting and changing the attribute of a class using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've highlighted the class which I want to change one of its attributes...

[image]

How to select and change the opacity attribute and change it to 0.1 using jQuery?

I've tried this with no success...

```
var item = $('.slide-object slide-object-stategroup shown')

$(item).attr( 'opacity' ): 0.1;
```

Comment: Use [`css()`](https://api.jquery.com/css). You also don't need to create another jQuery object from `item` as it already is one. Then you need to pass the `0.1` value as the second argument to the function call: `item.css('opacity', 0.1);`

Comment: Also your selector is wrong, it would be `$('.slide-object.slide-object-stategroup.shown')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your selector is wrong.
2. The way you are changing opacity is wrong.

See the code below:

```
var item = $('.slide-object.slide-object-stategroup.shown')
$(item).css( 'opacity', 0.1);
```

Use `.css` method to change any css property. Also classes needs to have a `.` before their name. Spaces in selector means you are accessing the child. So remove the spaces and add a dot in the selector.

Comment: "Spaces in selector means you are accessing the child. So remove the spaces and add a dot in the selector" really helped.

Comment: One last question: what if I want to change the transform-origin:24px 124px;